# 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'autofmt_xdate'

Tags: matplotlib

A project I previously submitted for a course worked as expected. I went back to run the code again and now get an python traceback error message that didn't occur before:
'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'autofmt_xdate'

I loaded the weather station data files and ran all the code, which previously worked.  Below is the code for the visualization plot:

```
plt.figure()

plt.plot(minmaxdf.loc[:,'Month-Day'], minmaxdf.loc[:,'min_tmps'] ,'-', c = 'cyan', linewidth=0.5, label = '10yr record lows') 
plt.plot(minmaxdf.loc[:,'Month-Day'], minmaxdf.loc[:,'max_tmps'] , '-', c = 'orange', linewidth=0.5, label = '10yr record highs')

plt.gca().fill_between(range(len(minmaxdf.loc[:,'min_tmps'])), minmaxdf['min_tmps'], minmaxdf['max_tmps'], facecolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5), alpha = 0.5)
plt.scatter(minbreach15.loc[:,'Month-Day'], minbreach15.loc[:,'min_tmps_breach15'], s = 10, c = 'blue', label = 'Record low broken - 2015')
plt.scatter(maxbreach15.loc[:,'Month-Day'], maxbreach15.loc[:,'max_tmps_breach15'], s = 10, c = 'red', label = 'Record high broken - 2015')
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabel('Temperature (Tenths of Degrees C)')
plt.title('10yr Max/Min Temperature Range for Wilton CT 06897')
plt.gca().axis([0, 400, -500, 500])
plt.xticks(range(0, len(minmaxdf.loc[:,'Month-Day']), 30), minmaxdf.loc[:,'Month-Day'].index[range(0, len(minmaxdf.loc[:,'Month-Day']), 30)], rotation = '-45')
plt.xticks( np.linspace(0, 15 + 30*11 , num = 12), (r'Jan', r'Feb', r'Mar', r'Apr', r'May', r'Jun', r'Jul', r'Aug', r'Sep', r'Oct', r'Nov', r'Dec') )
plt.legend(loc = 4, frameon = False)
plt.gca().spines['top'].set_visible(False)
plt.gca().spines['right'].set_visible(False)
plt.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

produced a chart of day of year (2004-14) 10yr average temp max/mins, overlay with scatter points of 2015 max/mins that exceeded the averages.

Answer (score 5):

[`autofmt_xdate()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.autofmt_xdate) is a method of the `Figure`. The command hence needs to be

```
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

Comment: Thank you for the guidance - that worked.  I am new to Python, Anaconda, Jupyter so learning the ropes.  What I don't understand is that my code worked fine about 2 months ago, but required your change today.  Do you have insight on why this is the case?  I have been using the same version of Python for several months 3.7, but updated matplotlib today to dea with another issue which is still outstanding.

Comment: I am not aware of `autofmt_xdate` ever been a function of the pyplot module. Which version did you use previously?

Comment: I was using matplotlib 2.2.3 previously and just switched to 3.0.2

Comment: would you also happen to know why the plots are not showing up and instead I get the messages:

"IPython.core.display.Javascript object"

"IPython.core.display.HTML object"